# R to LaTeX - use xtable to produce long table with line wrapping

Tags: r, export, latex

I have a table with a large number of rows (90) and each contains a name, a definition, plus another text column.  I am trying to output to latex such that this spans multiple pages and also fits to page width.

```
library("xtable")
glossary2<-data.frame(names=letters[1:4],definition=c("very long long long text","very long long long long long text","very long long long long long long text","very long long long text"),include=c(NA,"YES",NA,"NO"))
glossaryprint<-xtable(glossary2,label="tab:codebook",caption="glossary")
```

Further to the [xtable documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) I have been able to produce the following

To make it fit to page width:

```
align(glossaryprint)<-"lXXX"
print(glossaryprint,tabular.environment="tabularx",width="\\textwidth")
```

To make it fit over multiple pages:

```
print(glossaryprint,tabular.environment="longtable",floating=FALSE)
```

However, combining the two techniques is causing me difficulties.  I think I may have to have split the table into tables of say 20 rows each and use tabularx but that's very clunky and a lot of repeating code.

Is anyone able to suggest a method for making one long table fit to page width and linewrap inside columns when outputting to Latex using R functions?

Comment: You may want to look on the [TeX SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) for general solutions and then work them back into `xtable`. For example, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/set-longtable-to-fit-the-page-width) looks helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I have attempted to implement the `tabu` option but I'm on an ubuntu headless (non-GUI) server which does not have `tlmgr` and `tabu` is not available from the package cache (`apt-cache search tabu`) and trying to install it manually is well outside of my abilities!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Will leave this open for a more elegant solution but...

The addition of this line allowed the hardcoding of column widths

```
library("xtable")
glossary2 <- data.frame(names=letters[1:4], definition=c("very long long long text","very long long long long long text","very long long long long long long text","very long long long text"), include=c(NA,"YES",NA,"NO"))
glossaryprint <- xtable(glossary2, label="tab:codebook", caption="glossary")

align(glossaryprint) <- "lp{2in}p{3in}p{1in}" #here is the change
print(glossaryprint, tabular.environment="longtable", floating=FALSE)
```